# Rust function pointer to winapi LPVOID

Tags: winapi, rust, ffi, abi, detours

I am doing a CTF and for that I would like to use the ms detours library in rust. I found rust bindings to the detours lib (detours-sys). DetourAttach call wants to receive a pointer to a pointer to a function as first parameter.

```
fn hook_cwtick() {
unsafe {
    let module_name = "GameLogic.dll";

    // this returns the correct value I checked in x32dbg
    let func_loc: CwTickFn = hook_game_func(module_name, "GameAPI::Tick(float)");

    {
        let str_format = format!("func address: {:p}", func_loc);

        MessageBoxW(null_mut(), win32_string(&str_format).as_ptr(), win32_string("Function location").as_ptr(), MB_OK);
    }

    let c_like_func = (std::mem::transmute::<CwTickFn, c_void>(func_loc));
    let c_like_hooked_func = std::mem::transmute::<CwTickFn, c_void>(hookedCwTick);

    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

    // this returns the compiler error
    DetourAttach(c_like_func, c_like_hooked_func);
    DetourTransactionCommit();
    }
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\lib.rs:75:22
   |
75 |         DetourAttach(c_like_func, c_like_hooked_func);
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected *-ptr, found enum `winapi::c_void`
   |
   = note: expected raw pointer `*mut *mut winapi::c_void`
                     found enum `winapi::c_void
```

This is probably some rookie rust mistake. I have tried to double dereference the c_like_func and passing it like **c_like_func but the compiler complained that it cannot be dereferenced.

Any input appreciated

Comment: Rookie mistake, indeed. The [crate](https://crates.io/crates/detours-sys) you are using has 3 releases, 2 of which were *"yanked"* within a day of being published. And the GitHub [repository](https://github.com/DianaNites/detours) has since been archived. This is not something you can use with any sort of confidence. And confidence is the bog standard ingredient when crossing language boundaries. While you *could* try to solve the immediate issue, you'll find yourself hitting ever more down the road.

Comment: cheers for the input, I will try to switch to detour-rs then see if I can find any success with that one.